# When a C++ lambda expression has a lot of captures by reference, the size of the unnamed function object becomes large

Tags: c++, lambda, g++4.8

The following code:

```
int main() {
    int a, b, c, d, e, f, g;
    auto func = [&](){cout << a << b << c << d << e << f << g << endl;};
    cout << sizeof(func) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

outputs 56 compiled with **g++ 4.8.2**

Since all local variables are stored in the same stack frame, remembering one pointer is sufficient to locate the addresses of all local variables. Why the lambda expression constructs a so big unnamed function object?

Comment: It's implementation dependent whether a single pointer to the stack frame is stored, or whether pointers or references to each captured object is stored. In your case, it seems to be the latter. Assuming you're using a 64-bit platform, 7 variables * 8 bytes per pointer = 56.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not understand why you seem surprised.

The C++ Standard gives a set of requirements, and every single implementation is free to pick any strategy that meets the requirements.

Why would an implementation optimize the size of the lambda object ?

Specifically, do you realize how that would tie down the generated code of this lambda to the generated code for the surrounding function ?

It's easy to say *Hey! This could be optimized!*, but it's much more difficult to actually optimize and make sure it works in all edge cases. So, personally, I much prefer having a simple and working implementation than a botched attempt at optimizing it...

... especially when the work-around is **so easy**:

```
struct S { int a, b, c, d, e, f, g; };

int main() {
    S s = {};
    auto func = [&](){
        std::cout << s.a << s.b << s.c << s.d << s.e << s.f << s.g << "\n";
    };
    std::cout << sizeof(func) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

[Look Ma: 4 bytes only!](http://ideone.com/h22KzL)

Comment: That would be 8 bytes in 64-bit systems which the question seems to be based on, since it uses 56 bytes for 7 pointers.

Comment: @Kleist: yes, most probably, but this is implementation/platform dependent. It would be conceivable to embed further information in the lambda in debug mode, for example, or to be able to completely optimize away the reference itself in this case, ... so I only wanted to point out it was *slimmer* :)

Comment: I don't think this work-around is easy when the function is complex (probably having many different nested blocks) and the lambda expression may use a lot of different local variables. It requires reorganizing the structure of the entire function. I still accept your answer, though.

Answer (score 3):

It is legal for a compiler to capture by reference via stack pointer.  There is a slight downside (in that offsets have to be added to said stack pointer).

Under the current C++ standard with defects included, you also have to capture reference variables by pseudo-pointer, as the lifetime of the binding must last as long as the referred-to-data, not the reference it directly binds to.

The simpler implementation, where each captured variable corresponds to a constructor argument and class member variable, has the serious advantage that it lines up with "more normal" C++ code.  Some work for magic `this` need be done, but other than that the lambda closure is a bog-standard object instance with an inline `operator()`.  Optimization strategies on "more normal" C++ code will work, bugs are going to be mostly in common with "more normal" code, etc.

Had the compiler writers gone with the stack-frame implementation, probably reference capture of references in that implementation would have failed to work like it did in every other compiler.  When the defect was resolved (in favor of it working), the code would have to be changed again.  In essence, the compilers that would have used a simpler implementation would almost certainly have had fewer bugs and more working code than those who used a fancy implementation.

With the stack-frame capture, all optimization for a lambda would have to be customized for that lambda.  It would be equivalent to a class that captured a `void*`, does pointer arithmetic on it, and casts the resulting data to typed pointers.  That is going to be **extremely hard** to optimize, as pointer arithmetic tends to block optimization, especially pointer arithmetic between stack variables (which is usually undefined).  What is worse is that such pointer arithmetic means that the optimization of stack variable state (eliminating variables, overlapping lifetime, registers) now has to interact with the optimization of lambdas in entangled ways.

Working on such an optimization would be a good thing.  As a bonus, because lambda types are tied to compilation units, messing with the implementation of a lambda will not break binary compatibility between compilation units.  So you can do such changes relatively safely, once they are a proven stable improvement.  However, if you do implement that optimization, you really really will want the ability to revert to the simpler proven one.

I encourage you to provide patches to your favorite open-source compiler to add this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Because that's how it's implemented. I don't know if the standard says anything about how it should be implemented but I guess it's implementation defined how big a lambda object will be in that situation.

There would be nothing wrong for a compiler to store a single pointer and use the offsets, to do what you suggest, as an optimization. Perhaps some compilers do that, I don't know.

Comment: I would be very surprised if any compiler did, or planned to. It's easy to work around (just pack everything into a struct), and would complexify the generation of the code by introducing inter-dependencies between functions (the outer and the lambda) that are today independent and may freely reorganize their code.

Comment: You are probably right that it wouldn't make much sense to make that optimization for a compiler.